# Liquibase date_trunc postgresql function error while JHipster Prod version build

Tags: postgresql, maven, jhipster, liquibase

I am trying to build View PostgreSQL table in Liquibase for my JHipster application. Therefore, I have tried [createView](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_view.html) and [sqlFile](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) methods. 
My query has **date_trunc()** function as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW periodical_statistics AS
 SELECT tran.id, date_trunc('day', tran.pub_date) as, ...
  FROM transaction tran
  ...(LEFT JOINS - not relative)...
  WHERE ...(condtions - not relative)...
```

When I run my JHispster app as **Dev** Mode in maven(`./mvnw`). It is working ver fine.

But when I run it as **Prod** Mode in maven(`./mvnw -Pprod package`). It gives following error.

```
    20180817101122-1::liquibase-docs failed.  Error: Function "DATE_TRUNC" not found; 
SQL statement: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW periodical_statistics AS ....
```

is there are any way to solve this error problem?

Comment: I didn't mention my transaction table structure. As obvious, there is pub_date(dateTimeWithTimeZone) columm and I want to trunc it until day

Comment: Which maven phase fails? Does it fail also when running `./mvnw -Pprod package -DskipTests`?

Comment: are you using same users for dev/prod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `dbms='postgresql'` to the changeset. Liquibase recognized the 'date_trunc' function. It is as following:

```
    <changeSet author="sanatbek" id="20180904094713" dbms="postgresql">
            <createView replaceIfExists="true"
                        schemaName="public"
                        viewName="periodical_statistics">
                SELECT
                tran.id
                date_trunc('day', tran.pub_date) as truncated_date,
                ....
                ...(LEFT JOINS - not relative)...
                WHERE ...(condtions - not relative)...
            </createView>
        </changeSet>
```